# The memory of SQL grow up so fast

Tags: sql-server-2012

By monitoring its memory in Task Manager, I see that the sqlservr.exe takes almost memory (59/64gb).

I want to know some things:

1. Does it include data? I mean when we select/insert/update/delete records, it will affect to memory?
2. How about cached memory? Such as global temp table, stored procedures?

Please advices. I don't know exactly what is causing the problem so that I can solve it.

I'm very appriciated for your helps.

Comment: Yes, it's 99% data and it's good because it means SQL Server will be able to work mostly in-memory which is way faster than disk IO. You can configure SQL Server to a max. amount of memory if you must.

Comment: The way I understand it, SQL Server will release some of the memory it uses if the overall system available memory becomes low.

Comment: Don't know if you found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) already, but it should provide some information on SQL Server's memory management.